# How can I prevent user input from being shown on IDLE python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want both players to make a choice between (rock, paper or scissors) without the OTHER player seeing what they chose.

CODE:

```
player1_choice = getpass.getpass (prompt='\n[rock]\n[paper]\n[scissors]\nPlayer 1 please choose:')
```

CODE RUN:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
 File "C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\getpass.py", line 100
 return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.

[rock]
[paper]
[scissors]
Player 1 please choose: rock #(I want 'rock' input to be hidden, yet is still being showed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is caused by the IDLE itself. Try running the same code in the normal terminal:

```
python your_game.py
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that today myself. 